# Joomla database administration

Tags: database, joomla

I'm learning Joomla now and I have some problems with understanding its logic. 
I need a database table with records which user can get from there via form search. And I want site administrator to have a possibility to add and remove records from this table. So, I know what to do with user part, but can't find out how to create necessary table and fill it by administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a component to achieve that, you can take a look at  [http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aComponent_Development) for tutorials.